# "maven clean install" for ONOS

Tags: maven

I follow this link on ONOS (Open Network Operating System) to install ONOS on my Ubuntu 16.04 machine. Installation process failed after run command "mvn clean install" in onos directory.

`--debug` switch show that error caused by `"access denied" and "ReasonPhrase:Forbidden" while transferring artifact from repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/`, for example:

```
> Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException:
> Could not transfer artifact
> org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:pom:3.2.0 from/to central
> (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Access denied to:
> https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/felix/maven-bundle-plugin/3.2.0/maven-bundle-plugin-3.2.0.pom
> , ReasonPhrase:Forbidden.
```

Gooogle does not help me anymore :(

**Update:**
Some people got the same problem to me. I test it carefully again.

- wget, curl: 403 forbidden -> I can still connect, but the server
  didn't accept my request, even from "maven clean install" command.
- FireFox, Chrome: ok.

Why??? How can I configure maven to make it works like the FireFox and Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to connect to https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 to download the artifact. Check your network connection.

If your machine is behind proxy then follow the [guidelines to configure proxy settings](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html)

Comment: I update my question while my server able to establish connection to maven repo server. But the server give me 403 status code.

Comment: This might be because of proxy configuration, it is configured for browsers, can you check how  firefox  is configure enter url "about:preferences#advanced" then go to network --> settings

Comment: My server directly connected to the internet. What is the proxy here?